# Transform Apache Cookie logs to json with rsyslogd

Tags: apache-2.4, rsyslog, logstash, cookies, http-cookie

I am logging cookie headers, some cookies may have due date, some others not, the same is tru for other cookie parameters, I need to implement a centrilaized logging, so before sending those to logstash I want to transform syslog to json. How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried changing it to json in the apache httpd "logformat" before sending it to syslog?

Comment: @ezra-s any guides?

Comment: basically read "http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats" and define a format following your exact needs, it is not difficult to format logs to be printed as json entries.

Comment: @ezra-s any example? I have red that doc many times and red again.

Comment: See my reply to your question, there you can see an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is you format logs in apache as json previously.

As per requested here is an example I got on how to use LogFormart in httpd so your apache logs are logged directly like json:

```
LogFormat "{\"time\":\"%{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z}t\",\"clientip\":\"%a\",\"duration\": %D,\"status\": %>s,\"request\": \"%U%q\",\"uri\": \"%U\",\"remote_user\": \"%u\",\"query_string\": \"%q\",\"document\": \"%f\",\"bytes\": %B,\"request_method\": \"%m\",\"referer\": \"%{Referer}i\",\"useragent\": \"%{User-agent}i\",\"vhost\": \"%{Host}i\" }" json
```

Comment: thanks a lot, however this is only for crafting json from apache mod_log variables. I use {VARNAME}C for now, but that is not a good solution, as my goal is to collect all cookies, even the ones I am not aware of.